# Mysql query with more than one aggregate function

Tags: mysql, view

I have this table:

```
EMPLOYEES(Code, Name, Surname, Type, Department, Salary)
```

I need to display the department with the HIGHEST total expense for salaries WITHOUT using a view. Is that possible? The solution with a view is this:

```
CREATE VIEW DEPEXPENSES (DEPNAME, EXPENSE) AS  
SELECT DEPARTMENT, SUM(SALARY)  
FROM EMPLOYEES  
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT

SELECT DEPNAME  
FROM DEPEXPENSES  
WHERE EXPENSE=(SELECT MAX(EXPENSE) FROM DEPEXENSES)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your text says samething else than your code does

Comment: You're right, I've edited the message just now.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not too clear, but I think you want to run your second query without using a view. One solution is this:

```
select
  DEPARTMENT,
  SUM(SALARY)  
from
  EMPLOYEES  
group by
  DEPARTMENT
having
  SUM(SALARY)=(
    select MAX(SALARY) from (
      select DEPARTMENT, SUM(SALARY) as SALARY
      from EMPLOYEES  
      group by DEPARTMENT
    ) s
  )
```

(you can apply a max aggregated function on a subquery that already contains an aggregated function)

Comment: You're right, I've corrected my message. I know that some DMBS doesn't recognize a select in the having clause, so I need to find some other way (if it exists!). Thanks.